# Improving performance for view with too many UIButtons

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've got a view controller that handles a lot of complex on-screen controls. One of these is a sliding menu that contains 9 `UIButton` controls drawn in a grid using constraints, like so:

[image]

The load time of this view controller is nearly 3 seconds on device, and I've narrowed down the cause to the quantity of `UIButtons` inside this view. (I originally thought it was because it was being drawn off screen, but moving it to the center of the view controller didn't help).

I'm trying to come up with a way to improve the performance of these buttons, but I'm not really sure which direction to go. Will loading them in a `UICollectionView` help? Or is there a way to lazy-load the buttons so that they're drawn after the view controller is presented?

Comment: Nice buttons is nothing and won't be a performance issue in itself. It may be the constraints. Layout the buttons in code. Such a layout is trivial and the code would likely be much faster.

Comment: setting the constraints in sotryboard or set them through code have same effect ? @rmaddy

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. Don't use constraints. Layout the buttons by setting their frames. It will be much more efficient.

Comment: @rmaddy for that much effort, I might as well just stick them into a UICollectionView no? Then I won't even need to write the layout code - I can just init the buttons in the cells?

Comment: It's trivial effort. And a collection view probably won't be any more efficient than using constraints.

Comment: Alright, will give that a shot.

Comment: You can use UICollectionView because UICollectionView is easy to maintain this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out migrating this to a UICollectionView (even using constraints written in code) has made a significant performance improvement to this view controller.

It also has the added benefit of supporting paged views - more than 9 controls in the menu.